# Highcharts 3d scatter click does not work

Tags: highcharts, internet-explorer-8, click, scatter

I'm building a graph using Highcharts-3d v.4.1.4 and a click does not work  - `plotOptions.scatter.point.events.click`. I use IE8.0.7601.17514 and jQuery 1.11.0. Chart works perfectly fine in chrome and ie11.

As example I take [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/):

```
     plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            depth: 10,
            point:{
                events:{
                    click: function(event){
                        alert('hello');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did so:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'first_graph',
        type: 'scatter',
        backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd',
        height:800,
        events:{
            click: function(event){
                if (this.hoverPoint!=null){
                  alert('Hi!'); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with general issue in IE8/9 with click event.

Related topic: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4045